# Adobe Flash Animate CC HTML5 ads on DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP) solution

Tags: javascript, html, flash, adobe, google-dfp

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppWon.jpg)[Image2[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0FpE.jpg)> Ref URL:

> https://medium.com/@adguns/how-to-launch-adobe-animate-cc-html5-ads-with-actionscript-on-doubleclick-for-publishers-dfp-f61604230727
>
> Please follow below code: (Use code which are in BOLD)
>
> Change ALL image names to variables (IMG1, IMG2…):
>
> manifest: [ {src:IMG1, id:"adgunslogo325x120"}, {src:IMG2, id:"bg"} ]
>
> Add some JavaScript code to the  part above definition of your
>   main JS file, with those variables:
>
> IMG1 = "adgunslogo325x120.png"; // adgunslogo325x120.png IMG2
>   = "bg.jpg"; // bg.jpg
>
> Define clickTag variable in the banner HTML file:
>
> var clickTag = "http://adguns.lt/services/banners";
>
> Add Preloader to the main HTML file with simple JS function after
>   below code:
>
> var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container,
>   fnStartAnimation;
>
> images = new Array();
>
> function preload() { for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
>   images[i] = new Image(); images[i].src = preload.arguments[i] } }
>   preload(IMG1);
>
> Add processed images calculation to the image assets that are loaded
>   in to the canvas:
>
> this.initialize(images[0]); window.processedImages++; <…>
>   this.initialize(images[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXvAU.jpg)); window.processedImages++; <…>
>
> modify “function handleComplete() as mention below:
>
> function handleComplete(evt,comp) {
>       //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token
>   create_stage.
>       var lib=comp.getLibrary();
>       var ss=comp.getSpriteSheet();
>       var queue = evt.target;
>       var ssMetadata = lib.ssMetadata;
>       for(i=0; i
>
> ```
> processingInterval = setInterval(function() {
>     if (processedImages >= lib.properties.manifest.length) {
>         clearInterval(processingInterval);
>         stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
>         stage.addChild(exportRoot);
>         stage.update();
>         stage.enableMouseOver();
>
>         createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
>         createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
>     }
> }, 50);
>
> stage = new lib.Stage(canvas);
> ```